# How does one define a "language" using a regular expression?

Tags: regex, math

I would like to define "some language" using a regular expression. The requirements are:

1. The language must contain an infinite number of strings.
2. The underlying alphabet must have at least three different characters.
3. I also need to draw a deterministic finite state automaton that accepts the strings of that language.
4. Give two character strings that are accepted by that finite state automaton and two that are not.

Given this set of requirements, I have thus far (based on my 20 years old memory of set theory and the math associated with it), come up with the following  and would appreciate some input from a set-theory, regular expression and formal language definition expert (I know there are many of you who have a deeply vested interest in this subject).

Does the following come even close to fulfilling (1) and (2) at least? What does (4) actually imply? For instance, if the set can hold infinite strings (in theory), as per requirement (1), then how can we fulfill requirement (4) which says "Given 2 strings that are accepted by the (FSA) and TWO THAT ARE NOT"???

My current (rather fallable) solution is:

Alphabet:

```
∑ = {s,a,e,t,n}
```

Language:

```
L* = { Ø , ∈ , taste, set, ate, sane, ….}
```

OR (using regular expression)

```
L* = [saetn]*
```

Any takers?

Thanks.

Comment: `[saetn]*` is "zero or more of any of the characters inside the []". In other words, your regex would allow for `ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss[billions and billions of  more s's]ssssss` as a valid word.

Comment: Ahh thank you. Am in learner mode today. Please feel free to offer a correct solution to that error.

Comment: well, to allow only the words you've got in there `(taste|set|ate|sane)*`. "zero or more of (taste OR set OR ate OR sane)"

Comment: Ah huh! thank u! I'm now tyring to figure out how limiting the set to those words, will tie in with the "Infinite strings" requirement in (1)..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Theoretical Computer Science, not Programming. It should go to http://cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the regular expression `[saetn]*` would accept all strings over the alphabet you chose, so you would be unable to find two which are not in the language (The language would be `L = Σ*`) and can't satisfy requirement (4).

```
 L = { Ø , ε , taste, set, ate, sane, ...}
```

is not a valid language, because a language cannot contain `Ø`. The empty set is not a string (and a language is a set of strings, not a set of sets). Let's remove the `Ø`.

```
 L = { ε , taste, set, ate, sane, ...}
```

> Does the following come even close to fulfilling (1) and (2) at least?

It doesn't fulfil (1), as there is no reasonable pattern for the `...` to have any meaning. The language looks finite.

```
 L = { ε , taste, set, ate, sane }
```

Would be a valid finite language where `ε` denotes the empty string. All finite languages are regular, since you can create an expression that is an `OR` of all the strings in the language (`|taste|set|ate|sane`).

It does fulfil (2), as you picked the alphabet `∑ = {s,a,e,t,n}`, which has 5 elements.

> What does (4) actually imply?

It means that the language can't contain all strings over the alphabet. There must be at least two strings in `Σ*` that are not in the language, and you must show what they are. That doesn't prevent the language from being infinite.

An example of an infinite language would be:

```
L = { ε, s, a, t, ss, aa, tt, sss, aaa, ttt, ssss, ... }
```

That language (over the alphabet `{s, a, t}`) contains all strings which have no more than one distinct character. One regular expression that would accept that language would be `s*|a*|t*`. The language is clearly infinite, and any strings which contain two different symbols, like `at` or `sat` are not in the language. That language satisfies all the requirements. There are many other languages that satisfy all the requirements.

I will leave the drawing of the DFA to you. If you have any questions about it, feel free to comment on my answer.

Comment: Thankyou Paulpro!! Perfect, My intuition was guiding to me focus on individual characters/alphabets and NOT words, as that would not facilitate infinite perumations based on the set of characters/alphabets. THAK YOU so much! I haven't done any of this since the early 90s , and don't even program (C++) any more. So, very rusty. Teaching meditation and yoga, doesn't bode well for my intellectual/cognititive processes either.

Comment: Am using JFLAP to do the DFA. Looking forward to it! :) **THANK YOU ** deeply.. Paulpro! Loved the way you isolated all the issues in my approach and came up with solutions. Amazing genius!